# ExpressionEngine: mod_rewrite directory to subdomain, while removing /index.php/

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, expressionengine

In ExpressionEngine, what’s the best way to mod_rewrite a directory to a subdomain, while keeping index.php out of the picture?

For example:

http://www.domain.com/index.php/group/template -> group.domain.com/template

I’ve seen variations that take ANY group and rewrite them to subdomains, but I only need one.

I’ve been tasked with porting over a subsite from a different server (that was also running EE). Normally, I’d just redirect group.domain.com to domain.com/group (index.php removal was already working), but that’s been deemed an unacceptable solution. And of course, this is time-sensitive.

I’ve been diving into Google and the EE docs/wiki for going on twelve hours and I’m starting to go cross-eyed. Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would craft your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(group|group/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://group.domain.com/template/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This example uses the ["File and Directory Check" Method](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/#File_and_Directory_Check_Method) of removing `index.php` from the URL and uses a [RewriteCond Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to instruct Apache to handle the requests for the "group" directory and all its sub-directories differently.

Any links to `domain.com/group/template` will be redirected to `group.domain.com/template/`.

If you care about letting crawlers know your content has moved and want to make the transition as seamless as possible, you can add a [301 Redirect](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93633) to your RewriteRule:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(group|group/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://group.domain.com/template/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will ensure that users and search engines are directed to the correct page.

Comment: Also, typing in group.domain.com/ is just showing data from the default group, and not group-specific pages.

Comment: The code snippet I provided should be placed in an `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `domain.com` site. The infinite looping you're experiencing may be explained if you accidentally put the same code into Apache's document_root for the `group.domain.com` site.